# How to fetch complex model with a result of select statment using fetchgoups and map

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin, jooq

I'm using Jooq with Kotlin and i want to write a statement that fetches data from a query that uses couple of tables using join statement(example attached)

The problem I'm facing is that I want to map the result to my complex model which consist of one to many relationships and also many to many.

According to my knowledge I know i can use fetchgroups operation in Jooq to some how map the records but i still can't figure out how to get the result into my model.

**my model:**

```
data class MicroserviceDto(
  val microservice_id: Long = 1,
  val microservice_name: String? = "",
  val endpoint: String? = "",
  val mappings: String? = "",
  val solutionDefinitionMinimalDtoList: List<SolutionDefinitionDto> = emptyList(),
  val projectFileDtoList: List<ProjectFileDto> = emptyList()
)

data class SolutionDefinitionDto(
  val solution_definition_id: Long = 0L,
  val solution_definition_name: String = "",
  val solutionId: String = "",
  val solutionVersion: String = ""
)

data class ProjectFileDto(
  val project_file_id: Long = 1,
  val model: String = "",
  val relativePath: String = "",
  val fileContentDtoList: List<FileContentDto> = emptyList()
)

data class FileContentDto(
  val file_content_id: Long = 1,
  val content: ByteArray = ByteArray(0)
)
```

**Link to my schema diagram**
[Database Diagram visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE8Go.png)

Explanation of the diagram:

1. **Microservice** has many to many relationship with **SolutionDefinistion**
2. **ProjectFile** has one to many relationship with **Microservice**
3. **ProjectFile** has one to many relationship with **SolutionDefinition**
4. **FileContent** has one to many with **ProjectFile**

I've created a view to represent my desired query with all tables and the join statements between them.

Here is the View:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Microservice_Metadata_by_Microservice_Id AS
select
  # microservice
  M.id as `microservice_id`,
  M.name as `microservice_name`,
  M.mappings,
  M.endpoint,
  # solution definition
  SD.id as `solution_definition_id`,
  SD.name as `solution_definition_name`,
  SD.solutionId,
  SD.solutionVersion,
  # project file of microservice
  PF.id as `project_file_id`,
  PF.relativePath,
  PF.model,
  # file content data of project file
  FC.id as `file_content_id`,
  FC.content
from Microservice M
       # get project file
       left join Microservice_SolutionDefinition MSD
                 on MSD.microserviceId = M.id
       left join ProjectFile PF
                 on PF.microserviceId = M.id
  # get data content
       left JOIN FileContent FC
                 on PF.id = FC.projectFileId
  # get solutions of microservice
       left join SolutionDefinition SD
                 on SD.id = MSD.solutionDefinitionId;
```

How can I implement such a Jooq dsl query that map the ResultSet to my data model